# 1000000-н слонов, 100-то вагонов

Tags: числительные

Я давно хотел, совы, спросить: а мы наращения прибавляем к числам только порядковым и никогда не прибавляем к количественным?

Если это правда, то следующие числительные, имеющие окончания, написанные в виде наращений, все неправильные: *в 5-ть часов, 6-ть часов, 100-то вагонов, 50-т кирок,  1000000-н слонов.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, наращения используются только с **порядковыми** числительными.

> Наращение (буквенное падежное окончание) используется в записи порядковых числительных: *10-й класс «Б»*; *ученик 11-го класса*; *1-й вагон из центра*; *5-й уровень сложности*; *занять 2-е и 3-е места*; *в начале 90-х годов*, *12-й маршрут*.

Если хотите подробности, можете ознакомиться с соответствующей статьёй на портале "Грамота.ру": [Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)

Comment: А почему было принято именно такое решение относительно порядковых и количественных числительных? Бывают случаи, когда хочется использовать наращение и для количественных числительных тоже, и я иногда-таки ( в неофициальных текстах) пишу его. Меня очень огорчает это правило.

Comment: @Sharon Потому что количество по умолчанию.

Comment: Какое еще умолчание? Хотелось бы знать обоснованность наращения в каждом варианте: зачем оно нам вообще нужно. Помогает быстро и правильно понять текст? Тогда пусть помогает в обоих случаях.

Comment: @Sharon То есть по дефолту. Чтобы видеть, когда не количество. Сами по себе цифры передают количество, а для другого к ним надо что-то добавить.

Comment: Яснее выражайте свою мысль.  Please, без дефолтов, будьте проще) Я считаю, что здесь оба варианта равноправны. Докажите, что это не так.

Comment: @Sharon Вы меня не слышите. Цифры сами по себе (по умолчанию, изначально) означают количество, чтобы было другое, надо что-то добавить. Так принято как минимум в славянских языках. Вам это надо доказать? Доказать, что 2 + 2 = 4? Сами это доказывайте.

Comment: Ладно, попробую доказать))